# bundle.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, express

The error pops when i try to load the javascript file saying `Failed to load resource` i used

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

but that didn't work either.

I tryed to access the file with

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

nope, didn't work. i searched over the internet, it's still returning an error.

Cause im trying to make a form and when the user submitted the form it should save the data but im just wasting my time on a express error :/

Comment: Does the bundle exist in the public folder?

Comment: How do i know??

Comment: What do you mean? You’re the one in control, so you should put the bundle there.

Comment: Im gonna create a public folder?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html